# Producing Copyright symbol in QB64

Tags: qb64

I'm trying to produce the Copyright symbol in QB64. I've tried &#169, and all the variations I can dream up for this, like &#O169, but none produces it. Anyone know a (simple) way to do this?

Comment: I'm relatively certain that QB64 is using the DOS character set (specifically, [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437)), which doesn't have a copyright symbol. If you don't have Unicode support, you'll be out of luck. The standard representation back in the day was `(c)`.

Comment: You'll need to switch to another code page, such as CP850, where it is mapped to `CHR$(184)`, or deal with [_MAPUNICODE](https://wiki.qb64.org/wiki/MAPUNICODE) to map the Unicode character to one of the character codes between 128 and 255 as you wish.  There is also FreeBASIC if you find QB64's Unicode handling too troublesome.  FreeBASIC has a [WString](https://www.freebasic.net/wiki/KeyPgWstring) type for working with text beyond the CP437 character set, likely inspired by C's own wide-character strings, and it's interoperable with system APIs like `MessageBox` on Windows as a result.

Comment: Thanks for that advice. I guess I'll use Cody Gray's advice and use the old-fashioned method (c).